# Specifying multiple conditions in bash for loop

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops, for-loop

So I want to pass a for loop in my bash script, and I want it to stop depending on two parameters:

```
for (( x=1; x<= 50 -a $array_position -lt ${#array[@]}; x++ ))
do
    echo ${array[$array_position]}
    array_position=$((array_position+1))
done
```

My intention is to have this for loop echo 50 consecutive array values [0] -- [50], but stop if $array_position reaches the end of the array before all 50 loop iterations complete.

Any help is appreciated, as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `-a` or `-lt` in your `for` statement. Change it to this:

```
for (( x=1; x<= 50 && $array_position < ${#array[@]}; x++ ))
```

Or to simplify the whole thing further:

```
for (( x=0;  x < 50 && x < ${#array[@]}; x++ ))
do
    echo "${array[$x]}"
done
```

Comment: This worked great, and solved my question of passing multiple parameters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to specify the array size as your test, and use a break statement if you reach 50:

```
for (( x=1; x<=${#array[@]}; x++ ))
do
    echo ${array[$array_position]}
    array_position=$((array_position+1))
    [ $x -eq 50 ] && break
done
```

Comment: I agree this is a good idea, but I would like to be able to pass multiple parameters for future use

Comment: dogbanes's solution is better in my opinion